# Realm, findAllSorted and distinct

Tags: android, realm, kotlin

I have a method like this:

```
override fun getStuff(): MutableList<Stuff> = realm.where(Stuff::class.java)
        .findAllSorted("timeStamp", Sort.DESCENDING)
        .distinct("otherId")
```

where `Stuff` is something has a `timeStamp` filed.
If I do:

```
storage.saveStuff(Stuff("a", otherId=1, timeStamp=1))
storage.saveStuff(Stuff("b", otherId=1, timeStamp=2))
storage.saveStuff(Stuff("c", otherId=1, timeStamp=3))
// Other stuff with different otherId
```

I expect:

```
storage.getStuff()[0].name == "c"
```

But it's not. It's `a`.
If I set `Sort.ASCENDING`, I still get `a`.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you confirm that each `timeStamp` actually has a unique value? If they are the same then sorting might not change anything. Just a thought.

Comment: The documentation does say "If the result is sorted, the first object will be returned in case of multiple occurrences", so it seems it should indeed return the `c` object instead of the `a`.

Comment: I'm running this code in a unit test, I'm literally using 1 2 3 4 as timestamps

Comment: Is this Realm version 1.2.0? Can you by chance try with 1.1.1?

Comment: @EpicPandaForce it doesn't work even on 1.1.1

Comment: You can find the issue about this problem here https://github.com/realm/realm-java/issues/3503